# Symfony Sonata Admin Bundle - expected numeric

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Hey my Seance entity have following fields :

```
- idseance
- day
- hour
- idmovie (references to Movie entity => id)
- idromm (references to Room entity => id)
```

When I want to list all seances everyting is ok, I see Movie title in col, but if I try to edit seance I have following error: 
Unable to transform value for property path "idmovie": Expected a numeric.

The same error occurs in idroom case.

Below is my configureFormField from SeanceAdmin

```
   $formMapper->add('day', 'datetime', ['label' => 'Data seansu', 'format' => 'y M d']);
    $formMapper->add('hour', 'time', ['label' => 'Godzina rozpoczęcia ']);
    $formMapper->add('discountticket', 'number', ['label' => 'Cena biletu ulgowego']);
    $formMapper->add('normalticket', 'number', ['label' => 'Cena biletu normalnego']);
    $formMapper->add('idmovie', 'integer', ['label' => 'Film']);
    $formMapper->add('idroom', 'integer', ['label' => 'Sala']);
```

If I remove idmovie and idroom, edit page load correctyl but I can't edit movie or room value of course.

Anyone have idea why it doestn't work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not done, you need to write annotations for the idmovie/idromm fields.

First, add this under your entity namespace : `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`

Then you have to annotate your fields like this :

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourBundle\Entity\Movie", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_movie", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 /
 private $idMovie;
```

Finally, in SeanceAdmin.php, you need to replace the `integer` type of your field by `entity` or `sonata_type_model`

You can see more about form field types here -> https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html